How to fetch all Solana Transaction (on pump.fun or raydium) for last month
i am looking for a good solution to get 50m - 100m transactions from a program (pump.fun or Raydium) to backtest my bot. I need the transaction data, so every buy or sell or just raw transaction happend on pump.fun or raydium for last 1-6 months.
Pump.fun had 43m tx last month, so thats the reason i need so many.
Sadly every API i found there is an limit of 1000 and getTransaction is a single request, so fetching 1m tx would take ages, is there a better service/provider/tool/api out there you guys use or heard about?
Would be awesome if you could share all you know, so me and everyone else reading it can check them out.
Here are my findings so far that havent worked for me :(

Ankr, when paying 20$ for Ankr you can get access to their Premium API which will allow you to send 1.5k of requests per second, which means you can send 1.5k getTransactions a second. Kinda nice if you only want to fetch thousands of tx.

Shyft, really nice API, it allows you to fetch bulk requests and other cool features, but only 100 at a time, so also not working for me.

Bitquery, graphql for solana, it should work, but when i did a v1 query, i got no response and instantly reached my points limit, even though i just set Limit to 1 transaction.

Dune, havent tried it out yet, it costs 400$ to get API and Download access to their DB, they have whole Solana History stored. I tested it for free, so i know it will work, but to get download access i need to pay 400$ which i will do when i dont find any other solution.

SolanaTracker, works if you need specific Token Transactions and not transactions for a program.

Flipside: not sure yet if it works but trying it out and share results here

Google BigQuery, technically it works, but because data isnt indexed it would make broke before i get even 1 day worth of data.


EDIT: FlipSide worked for me perfectly (100k tx per request, took me few h to get 1 month of data)
Thanks for all the answers btw, will add more services to the above list everytime i try something new.

Okay Flipside worked for me, i went through their docs and setup my code to fetch 100k of tx every request, after 3-4h i had 1month worth of data.

If you are interested how i have done it, let me know, i will share my code with ya.

Hi @Marvin Daum I have a similar questions https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/18386/fetch-transactions-per-year could you share you code with me?

Based on the data volume, I believe it's a good idea to try running your own node and serving data from there.
To get data, you could explore indexing services like Solana BigQuery (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/crypto-solana-mainnet-us?project=ardent-girder-403621&pli=1) or FlipSide (https://flipsidecrypto.xyz/livequery). For both, I’m unsure of the terms, conditions, and data loading limitations.
You should also check the Old Faithful project (https://old-faithful.net/), which stores all Solana history on FileCoin (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcmmQMkrqS4). Their documentation provides guidance on starting an RPC endpoint over the data: https://docs.old-faithful.net/usage-and-installation/rpc-server

I already tried Google BigQuery and it is unuseable, its not indexed which makes it extremely expensiv for simple querys.
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/17361/missing-indexes-in-google-bigquery-for-transactions
I will try out OF, sounds promising.

Flipside seems really promising, still need to test it and figure out the limits and all that, but really promising so far!

Thanks! Flipside worked for me!

OF is the only way to do this properly https://docs.old-faithful.net/

ouh thanks i will try it out

havent tried it out, flipside worked for me

Run your own node i think to get unlimited call

true, but isnt it difficult to setup?

I dont do for Solana but i need to do like you we can stay in contact !  The most difficult is to find a good tutorial ^^
But it require big composant like more 250 GB of RAM but they say same for BSC node but i run without big RAM but sometime i get desyncronise

Dang it, i only have 48 GB :D
Is there a way to just syncronize the data i need and then stop the process, i just want the latest 1 GB of tx or so.

I don't know maybe ask dev from helius or something like this to got this data but i don't think so try maybe in another way to get it
