Fetch transactions per year
Is any way to fetch all transactions/or block with transactions per year in Solana?
Currently I use the next way:

assign current_block as start block of the year
start with rpc call: getBlock
then increment current_block
loop again

but it's took a long time, because I have a limitation in API calls, event if I do it in parallel manner.

If you want to get all transactions, you need to fetch all blocks, there's no other option unfortunately! You might be able to go slightly faster with getBlocks instead, but you'll still be rate-limited: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblocks
